# How do you save a kable table as a png?

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I am making an html output with rmarkdown.
I’m trying to save a dataset as a kable table png and use it later. It is not failing or producing an error but is not saving any png file in the specified path. Any ideas why?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

dataset_kable <- dataset %>% select(ID, breed, location) %>%
Kable() %>%
Kable_styling(latex_option=c(“scale_down”,”HOLD_position”))

save_kable(x=dataset_kable, file=“PATH/dataset_kable.png)
```

No error shows up, it’s just not in the file explorer folder.

Comment: path is not an argument to `save_kable`, did you try your example? r is case sensitive

Comment: I think it's `file` rather than `path`, though whatever it is, it's the second argument so `save_kable(dataset_kable, “PATH/dataset_kable.png")` should do it (note your example is missing a closing quote after the file path)

Comment: Thanks both of you for your replies. I updated my question to more accurately show it with `file`. It doesn’t work as a png but does with an html extension.

Comment: i tried your code with a real data set after fixing the quotes and upper case problems, it works for me